# Popup freezes Selenium Webdriver until the popup is manually closed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having problems automating tests on an internal website. In some cases, a popup will freeze the test until I manually close the popup. After the popup is opened, no code is run, not even System.out.println's.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("top_toolbarSALTkA7_Aras_Tbi_promote")).click();
System.out.println("test");
```

I have tried multiple ways of handling the popup, but no code at all is run after the click(), and it seems it never times out.

Tried:

1.

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('top_toolbarSALTkA7_Aras_Tbi_promote', 'onClick')");
```

2.

```
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    for(String handle : windowHandles)
    {  
        driver.switchTo().window(handle);
        if (driver.getTitle().contains(title)) 
        {
            System.out.println("- (Page title is: " + driver.getTitle() + ")");
            break;  
        }  
    }
```

3.

```
driver.switchTo().alert();
```

4.

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

If I close the popup, the test will continue with the System.out.println and then continue until finshed.

I'm using Selenium Webdriver 2.48.2 with FireFox 31.0, programming is Java. Any ideas what can be done? (It's not possible to change the website)

Comment: What webdriver bindings are you using? when I use webdriverJS and I want to inject javascript into the browser I use `executeAsycScript()` instead of `executeScript()` - it takes a callback - which you invoke to  explicitly tell webdriver - the client side JS has finished - now continue running the rest of the tests

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention! I'm using java

Comment: Tried using this instead of executeScript() now, no change: `((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript("return document.getElementById('top_toolbarSALTkA7_Aras_Tbi_promote', 'onClick')");`

Comment: don't mean to be annoying, but did you try driver.switchTo().alert() **.accept()** ; instead of just driver.switchTo().alert();

Comment: Yes, I tried a lot of combinations of the above examples, I'm desperate :) Tried it again now, just to make sure, but it still won't work.

Comment: What kind of pop up is it?  If the popup launches from the OS then selenium can't interact with it. You can use profiles to handle this or Java's robot class.  Can you post a picture of your popup?

Comment: I tried to post a picture, but my reputation won't let me ... Here's a link: [link](http://i64.tinypic.com/2yjud75.jpg)

Comment: I would try to use different Firefox version (newer), then Chrome and see if anything will change

Comment: That's unfortunately not possible, the website is only compatible with Internet Explorer (which I cannot use because of the security settings, not allowed to change them at all) and Firefox 31.0

Comment: Are you sure your code switches windows? Try to debug by printing the window handle before and after the popup appears. When it's changed, try to locate your OK/Cancel button and click on it. It seems to me as a problem of context here.

Comment: Nothing happens after the popup is opened, not even println's, it doesn't print anything that I put in after the click() that opens the popup. I found this case yesterday, that seems pretty similar: [link](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1039/how-do-i-handle-the-login-modal-dialog-created-by-onload-in-a-webdriver-java-b), but unfortunately no solution there

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution!!! Found it in the Selenium official user group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/selenium-users/popup%7Csort:relevance/selenium-users/eDqPiYoJ9-Q/kRI67cCVe5wJ

Solution is to start a new thread that waits a couple of seconds, and then presses enter (or in my case first tabs to the "OK" button). Just call the function before the popup is opened.

```
    public static final void prepareToPressEnterKey(int seconds, int tabs) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            try { 
                Robot robot = new Robot();

                for (int i=0; i<tabs; i++)
                {
                    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                }

                robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); //press for 1 sec
                robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Prepare to Press Enter Exception");
            }
        }
    },
            seconds,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
}
```

Still, if there are any better solutions I'd very much like to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just disable popup. I mean you need to call the next script inside the current browser context (`executeScript` - I guess in your, Java binding case):

```js
document.alert = window.alert = alert = () => {};
```